# To number the pages of the book, n digits were used. Find the number of pages in the book

Tags: c#, algorithm

I tryed to do like this, but this algorithm is very slow. 1 <= n <= 10^9, so n is very large! Program must work no more 1sec

```
using System;

struct MainStruct
{
    private static void Main ()
    {
        int n = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
        int page = 1, count = 0;
        while (true) {
            count = count + page.ToString ().Length;
            if (count == n) {
                break;
            }
            page = page + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine (page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 51 ## Or whatever you want

pagesCovered = [(10**m)-1 for m in range(1, 10)]
digitSum = [(i+1)*9*(10**i) for i in range(10)]
cumulativeSum = [sum(digitSum[:j+1]) for j in range(len(digitSum))]
for k in range(len(cumulativeSum)):
    if cumulativeSum[k] > n:
        maxDigits = k + 1
        break

pages = pagesCovered[maxDigits - 2] + ((n - cumulativeSum[maxDigits-2]) / maxDigits )
```

(This is in `python`, but its algorithm can be applied to `C#` as well)

First, I generate a few `list`s:

1. pagesCovered --> a `list` of how many pages are covered with each digit (i.e. with 3 digits, 999 pages are covered in total)
2. digitSum --> a `list` of the sum of each digits (i.e. all of the 3 digit numbers have a sum of 2700, and all of the two digit numbers have a sum of 180)
3. cumulativeSum --> a `list` containing the cumulative sums of `digitSum`

Then, I find the first sum in `cumulativeSum` which is greater than `n`; the index of this sum tells us the max number of digits `n` has. Finally, I calculate the `pages` by finding out how many pages are covered with the digit 1 less than the max digit, and then divide the remainder by the maxDigits to get the pages.

Comment: This is not C#.  Also answers without explanation are not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
string NumberOfPages(int numberOfDigits)
{
    return "Between " +
        Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, numberOfDigits - 1)).ToString()
        + " and " +
        Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, numberOfDigits) - 1).ToString();
}
```

2 digit are needed for any number between 10 and 99, which are 10^1 and 10^2-1. Etc.